# Mvvmcross, how to access a ViewModel from my android project

Tags: mvvmcross

I have an Android app which uses a SupportActionBar that contains a bunch of tabs. These tabs each have a fragment that in turn are connected to a ViewModel in my core project. This works great and when i start the app they are all initialized right away and setup correctly.
What i would like to do is to call on a method on one of these ViewModels from my main activity that contains all the tabs and fragments.

I read in another post that in WP you could cast the DataContext to the ViewModel but that might not work in Android. I haven't been able to do this, maybe because my DataContext is not the currently displayed ViewModel but the MainViewModel connected to my main activity. Or maybe it's not supposed to be done that way, i'm not sure.

I'm trying to do this:

```
var test = (MessagesViewModel)this.DataContext;
test.GetViewDataFromApi();
```

To update the data in the view when i press the tab. I can't use the Init function for this for example since the ViewModel isn't recreated everytime i show the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to update some data in the tab's fragment when tab is selected?

If that's the case, one way to do it is to

1) handle the tab selection event to get the current tab(maybe using TabListener),

2) get the fragment (MvxFagment) in the selected tab

3) get the (IMvxViewModel) view-model from the fragment

4) call the method you need to update data on the view-model

I assume you are using a MvxFragment (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/Fragments/MvxFragment.cs?source=cc) so you can access the view-model from the MvxFragment's ViewModel property.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. It was step 3 that i hadn't figured out. Very obvious now afterwards. Many thanks!